# Can we create Static ActionResult method in Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Someone ask following question to me in interview, to which I cannot able to answer. Somebody please help me.

Can we create Static ActionResult method in controller? 
If yes. What is the benifits? and if no. What is the reason?

Comment: What is an "ActionResult method"? A method that happens to return an `ActionResult`? Of course; why not?

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT It's a bit late (but it's never too late). The answer to which you linked is about making static controllers (which does indeed sound like a bad idea), however this question was about static action methods in a regular controller. So in other words, your link is misleading and well, wrong.

Comment: @MarcinHabuszewski Thanks for pointing that out. I forget about MVC, and why I put that comment here. Anyway deleting the comment. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

If "ActionResult method" is a method that returns ActionResult, you can declare it static, of course, but it will not be called when you initiate that action. When calling some action, ASP.NET MVC creates an instance of the controller (using ControllerFactory), and since your method is static, it is not related to any instance, and thus, it will not be called by MVC

Comment: "and thus, it will not be called".  By MVC, no.  But can be called by another class or internally.

Comment: Additionally, you need a controller instance to return a view. You can declare a method static and return a string - but it will not be found.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think it is a good idea to create a static action method, as you will no longer have access to all the controller properties, such as controllercontext, etc.

Comment: Creating extensions for controllers shares those limitations too. Not being able to call the content generating methods (like `View`, `PartialView` etc.) is also a problem, but at least this can be partially overcome by manually creating specific `Result` classes rather than through the use of controller methods.